# What is difference between Google Market billing package and Google Play Billing lib

Tags: android

**What is difference between Google Market billing package and Google Play Billing lib**.Is it same?
        I am searching for Google Market billing package but i am not getting it after installing all the updates.I got only Google play billing lib.

Answer (score 2):

Google Market Billing enables you to charge for usage on mobile applications.

Regarding In-app billing, it is a Google Play service that provides checkout processing for in-app purchases. To use the service, your application sends a billing request for a specific in-app product.Both are different

More information can be had from this link.

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html

Comment: My question is google market billing package and google play billing lib are same or not ?